# Str to Unicode not working as expected in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-2.x

I am trying to match the exact format of a response. I have:

```
def recreate_metrics_format(self):
    MAP = {
        # "measurment_name": "measurement_name_",
        "ref": "measurement_ref_",
        "value": "measurement_value_"
    }
    IDs = 3
    metrics = []
    for this_id in range(1, IDs+1):
        this_metric = {}
        for k, v in MAP.items():
            key = k.encode('UTF-8')
            attribute = v + str(this_id)
            this_metric[key] = getattr(self, attribute)
        metrics.append(this_metric)
    return metrics
```

For some reason, even after adding the `encode` part, my format is off:

```
ipdb> expected_metrics
[{'ref': u'tenetur', 'value': 567.41}, {'ref': u'blanditiis', 'value': 1632.0}, {'ref': u'ducimus', 'value': 786.4862}]
ipdb> metrics
[{u'ref': u'tenetur', u'value': 567.41}, {u'ref': u'blanditiis', u'value': 1632.0}, {u'ref': u'ducimus', u'value': 786.4862}]
```

I do `unicode` instead of `encode` in shell and it works:

```
ipdb> unicode
<type 'unicode'>
ipdb> unicode('blah', 'UTF-8')
u'blah'
```

I've used `encode` before and it worked; what is wrong with using `encode` here?

Comment: I'm confused about what the problem is here ... With that said, I'd expect that you want to `.decode` the string into unicode ...

Comment: Seems like `expected_metrics` is **not** the expected result but **your** result?

Comment: no it's the expectaton, metrics is the result

Comment: I thought you encode to unicode, and only decode from unicode to ascii?

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please [edit] your question to include the entire short program. Please include the actual and expected output of the program. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I don't understand encode and decode in Python (2.7.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596623/i-dont-understand-encode-and-decode-in-python-2-7-3)